# Adding elements to a chart with Matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

ax = fig.gca()

```
pplt.grid(True)

pplt.plot(df['Date'], pivot, label="Pivot")

plt.show()
```

I'm drawing a graph with their code. `df['Date']` returns 160 rows of data. the number from the `pivot` is still equal to

I want to add one more data to this.

```
plt.plot(df['Date'], ema, label="EMA", linestyle='dashed')
```

but the problem is that 160 rows are coming from `df['Date']` but 100 rows of data is coming from ema and naturally it gives an error and does not generate the graph. The first 60 lines of `ema` are `nan` . what I want to do is pass the first 60 (or how many are empty) blanks and add them to the chart.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add `nan` values to the front of your ema list based on the difference in length of the ema list and the dataframe df. Then you can just plot both the pivot and the ema plots on the same graph:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

### Create mock data
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":np.arange(0,16)})
ema = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
pivot = np.arange(0, 16)[::-1]
##############

# fill the ema lsit with nan values based on the length of df
ema = [np.nan] * (len(df) - len(ema)) + ema 

plt.plot(df["Date"], ema, label = "ema")
plt.plot(df["Date"], pivot, label = "pivot")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: both]

If you just want the ema list plotted but want the range of x axis to be the same as the plot for the pivot table, then pass the xlim argument using the min value and max value of `df["Date"]`:

```py
plt.plot(df["Date"], ema, label = "ema")
plt.xlim(df["Date"].min(), df["Date"].max())
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: single]

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't adapt it to my own codes.

You can see all the codes below.

`ema=[]
ema.append(ta.EMA(df['Close'], timeperiod = 7))
print(ema)

When I run the code, I get the following result.
[0 NaN
1 NaN
2 NaN
3 NaN
...
16 10.099867
17 10.252569
18 10.634427
dtype: float64]`

I couldn't edit it as you mentioned.

Comment: The problem is we are working with limited information. If you could update your question with [minimal working information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we could better answer this. As it stands, I don't know what `ta` is or its column `EMA`. You need to provide us with an example of all your code so we can replicate it. See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73052433/faster-way-to-use-linkage-dataframes-with-other-dataframes-python) where I provide all needed examples to help others answer my question.

Comment: I fixed it after some work on it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Great! No problem

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly I would create an array with the correct dimension and fill it with the right values. Soimething like

```
ema_arr = np.zeros_like(df['Data'])
ema_arr.fill(np.nan)
ema_arr[-ema.size:] = ema
plt.plot(df['Date'], ema_arr, label="EMA", linestyle='dashed')
```

The first line creates an array the same length of `df['Data']` and fills it with 0s
The second line sets the last values of said array to the values of ema.
Finally the third line plots it.

Comment: I think you got it right.
     `ema_arr[-ema.size:] = ema
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'`
gave the error.
in my codes ema goes like this:
`ema=[]
ema.append(ta.EMA(df['Close'], timeperiod = 100))`

`When I run print(ema)
[101 rows x 7 columns]
[0 NaN
1 NaN
2 NaN
3 NaN
4 NaN
          ...
96 9.263071
97 9.283982
98 9.316198
99 9.361918
100 9.441200
Length: 101, dtype: float64]`

Comment: If ema is a list then you can use len(ema) instead of ema.size

Comment: When I add `ema_arr[len(ema)] = ema`, `ema_arr[len(ema)] = ema
ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy datetime` error.